# Basics of react-table: where do I put useTable when pulling data from an API?

Tags: react-hooks, react-table

I am trying to set up react-table but am running into the issue of not being able to call hooks inside regular functions, specifically the useTable hook. Say I have something like this:

```
const Search = () => {

    const [tableRows, changeTableRows] = useState([])
    const columns = [
        { Header: 'One', accessor: 'header1'},
        { Header: 'Two', accessor: 'header2'}
    ]
    const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } = useTable({ columns, tableRows })

    const apiSearch = (field, query) => {
        axios.get(`ip/querypath?query=${query}&field=${field}`)
        .then(({data}) => {
            changeTableRows(data)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

    return (
        /* Render forms to input data and call apiSearch, and render actual table */
    )
}
```

The line with useTable is only being called once, with no initial row data. I need it to update when I make the API call but I can't put a hook inside my apiSearch function. Even if I could, I don't know the right way to do it. This throws a syntax error:

```
let getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow

const apiSearch = (field, query) => {
    ...
    { getTableProps, getTablyBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } = useTable({ columns, tableRows })
}
```

I know I'm missing something basic and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Call API On mount?  do it in useEffect hook, Now pass Columns and Headers to table